# What is the html <select> element's name attribute's value

Tags: html, forms, select

I know this is very basic, but for the life of me, I can't find a web page anywhere that explains what the value is of the `name` attribute of the HTML `<select>` element.  Can someone please point me to a specification, or any website, for that matter, that explains what is the value of the `name` attribute of the `<select>` element?  Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a `<select>` element is inside a `<form>` The `name` attribute value will be the name of the field submitted by the form.
This value can be read in the submitted page from the Request.
For example if you have a `<select name="x">` and the selected `<option>` value is y, then in the submitted page it will look something like this:
`Request["x"]` will be equal y

Comment: Yea this is what I meant to ask.  I should have phrased my question better.  I meant, what is the value associated with the name key.

Answer (score 3):

**It's something like:**

The **`name`** attribute specifies the **name** for a drop-down list.
The **`name`** attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.

**For example:**

```html
<form>
<select name="cars">
  <option value="juice">juice</option>
  <option value="coca cola">coca cola</option>
  <option value="pepsi">pepsi</option>
  <option value="sprite">sprite</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

It's only a attribute for specify or reference the element.. No more, no less..

Answer (score -1):

The `name` attribute is common for all input elements, here is the explaination from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp):

> The name attribute specifies the name of an  element.
>
> The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or
>   to reference form data after a form is submitted.
>
> Note: Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values
>   passed when submitting a form.

It can take any value you want.

Comment: It cannot take _any_ value; it must not be blank. Also while w3schools is good to quickly find things, I would strongly discourage citing it. It is not an official specification and there are plenty of other good websites you can reference; like the official specifications themselves (for example w3c).

Comment: While I agree that w3schools might not be the perfect source, but still the explanation is simple and concise, nothing from that quote seems to be wrong :) And when I said any value I didn't mean empty but sure I didn't specify that. Thanks